# Expressing Fresnel Equations in terms of $\mathbf k$-vectors

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, vectors

> Write the Fresnel Equations in terms of the **k**-vectors (or the propagation constants $\gamma$). Assume that the x-direction is normal to the interface, and the z-direction is parallel to the interface, so that **k$^2$** = **k$_x^2$** + **k$_z^2$**

I've been working on this problem and I'm not entirely sure if my understanding is correct. Is this merely a case of expanding the $\left(\frac{E_R}{E_I}\right)$ and $\left(\frac{E_T}{E_I}\right)$ fractions in terms of the complete wave equations for the reflected, incident, and transmitted electric waves $E_R$, $E_I$, and $E_T$? Or is there supposed to be some other way to express either the index of refraction or the cosines of the incident and transmitted angles in terms of the **k**-vectors that I seem to be missing?